# ReactJS datepicker button hide

Tags: reactjs

This is my Datepicker. It is normal type=date picker. When I run the application and click on the datepicker, inside the popup window there are two buttons. clear button and today button. Is there a way to remove or disable these buttons.

[image: Code]
[image: Output]

Is there a way to remove or disable these buttons.

Comment: I would prefer to use `react-datepicker` library for more customization and functionality.

Comment: You can use `@mui/x-date-pickers`. https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/

Comment: What library are you using? Show the code

Answer (score 0):

The appearance and behavior of the datepicker, including "Clear" and "Today" buttons, are determined by the browser and operating system. Unfortunately, the HTML input element with type="date" provides limited customization options.

If you wish to have customisation and changes as per your requirements, I suggest you use libraries or packages. There are various sources for this.